# Google Embed API charts disappearing when state changed in angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, google-api, angular-ui-router, google-analytics-api

First time charts loading with a great charm. If i changed the state and back to analytics page, nothing is loading. No changes in reloading the particular page using $scope.reload. If i reload the browser Embed API working. Unable to find where the problem is?

**My html file**

```
<section id="auth-button"></section>
<section id="view-selector"></section>
<section id="timeline"></section>
<script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fjs){
        g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(cb){this.q.push(cb)}};
        js=d.createElement(s);fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics')};
    }(window,document,'script'));
</script>
<script>
    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

        // Step 3: Authorize the user.

        var CLIENT_ID = 'usedclientid';

        gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
            container: 'auth-button',
            clientid: CLIENT_ID
        });

        // Step 4: Create the view selector.

        var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
            container: 'view-selector'
        });

        // Step 5: Create the timeline chart.

        var timeline = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
            reportType: 'ga',
            query: {
                'dimensions': 'ga:landingPagePath',
                'metrics': 'ga:sessions,ga:bounceRate',
                'start-date': '30daysAgo',
                'end-date': 'yesterday',
                'sort': '-ga:sessions',
                'max-results': 5
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'TABLE',
                container: 'timeline',
                options: {width: '100%'}
            }
        });
 gapi.analytics.auth.on('success', function(response) {
            viewSelector.execute();
        });

        viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
            var newIds = {
                query: {
                    ids: ids
                }
            }
            timeline.set(newIds).execute();

        });
    });
```

**Routing file**

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/creation/blog');
        $stateProvider
            .state('creationblog', {
                url: '/creation/blog',
                controller:'creationblogCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'views/creation/creblog.html'
            })

            .state('analyticsreport', {
                url: '/report/analytics',
                controller: 'repanalytics',
                templateUrl: 'views/report/analytics.html'
            });
    }]);
```